# Mathematician who talked about the probability of a "good" graph?

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, graph-theory

In my undergraduate years, one of my professors always talked about this one mathematician who was talking about "good" graphs and wondered about the existence of such a graph. Apparently this mathematician could not find such a graph, and then proceeded to show that the probability that such a graph existed was 1 by using a probability measure.

Does anyone know to whom my professor was referring? [I apologize if such a question is inappropriate for this site.]

Comment: It's quite a vague question (there are few details and its not clear what specific graph the mathematician was looking for) so I'm not sure that you're going to get a good response.

Comment: If I knew what a "good" graph was, believe me, I would have defined it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure without more context, but my best guess is the mathematician was Paul Erdős and technique you are talking about is [the Probabilistic Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_method).

Comment: Yes! It was Erdos! (I wasn't 100% sure on that.) Thank you!

Comment: Your welcome, glad to help! The Probabilistic Method is a great tool to prove existence.